# Can we deduce that $f(A)⊂A$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $(f_{n})_{n≥1}$ be a sequence of continuous functions verifying $$f_{n}(A)⊆A$$  for all $n≥1$. Here $A$ is a compact set. Assuming that this sequence converges uniformly to a continuous function $f$

My **question** is: Can we deduce that $$f(A)⊆A$$

If no, Is there some conditions on the functions $(f_{n})_{n≥1}$ in which we can get the inclusion for the limiting function $f$.

Comment: Does $\subset$ mean $\subsetneq $ or $\subseteq$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: It is a strict inclusion without equality.

Comment: Then consider $A=[-1,1]$ and $f_n(x)=(1-\frac1n)x$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ is compact then $A$ is closed. Thus $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a sequence in $A$ that converges to $f(x)$. Since $A$ is closed, $f(x) \in A$ for all $x \in A$. Thus, $f(A) \subseteq A$.